# How to interact with an SMTP server with PHP through fsockopen/fwrite/fread/fgets

Tags: php, smtp

I'm wondering how to correctly interact with an SMTP server with PHP through `fsockopen/fwrite/fread/fgets` etc. The major problem appears to be that you don't quite know when to stop reading the response after a command was sent.

I analyzed a few publicly available PHP scripts but didn't see a proper way of doing that. My below script does IMO two things right:

- It reads *all* lines the server returns. A user script presented at [getmxrr.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php) for example reads only 2 lines... (`for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) $s.=fgets($fp, 1024);`)
- It compensates for the lack of a clear "I'm done" signal from the server by setting a stream timeout.

However, this is slow. After every command you need to wait 2s for the timeout to kick-in.

```
// error handling and such missing on purpose to keep it short
$host = "some-MX-host.com";

$commands = array();
$commands[] = "EHLO microsoft.com\r\n";
$commands[] = "MAIL FROM:<>\r\n";
$commands[] = "RCPT TO:<foo@some-MX-host.com>\r\n";

@$fp = fsockopen($host, 25);
stream_set_timeout($fp, 2);

foreach ($commands as $command) {
  echo $command;
  fwrite($fp, $command);
  while ($line = fgets ($fp)) {
    print $line;
  }
}

fclose($fp);
```

How can that be improved?

Side note... Some servers are really slow to respond to certain email addresses in `RCPT TO:<foo@some-MX-host.com>` (usually if invalid due to typo or so). Hence, a timeout of 2s is usually not good enough. Hence, for better performance you want a lower timeout for most commands (e.g. 1s) and a higher timeout for the `RCPT TO` (e.g. 5s). This may improve performance but complicate the implementation.

**Update 2016-05-02**

The following modification will reduce the global timeout but still wait longer if the server needs some extra time for certain commands. I'm quite pleased with how that performs but I still doubt there isn't anything more elegant.

```
stream_set_timeout($fp, 1);

foreach ($commands as $command) {
  echo $command;
  fwrite($fp, $command);
  // Wait at most 10 * timeout for the server to respond.
  // In most cases the response arrives within timeout time and, therefore, there's no need to wait any longer in such
  // cases. However, there are cases when a server is slow to respond. This for-loop will give it some slack.
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $response = "";
    while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
      $response .= $line;
    }
    // Only continue the for-loop if the server hasn't sent anything yet.
    if ($response != "") {
      break;
    }
  }
  echo $response;
}
```